# Change column value of random sample of subset of pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Have a pandas dataframe of the form

```
col1 col2 col3     tochange
a1   a2   group1   a4
b1   b2   group1   b4
...
i1   i2   group2   i4
...
```

where col3 denoted a binary category of labels for each row (ie. a row can be in either group1 or group2).

Would like to set the tochange values to some constant for a random sampling of the subset of the dataframe where the rows are in group2. Ie. Change the tochange values of X random rows in the dataframe *subset* `df[df['col3'] == 'group2']` to all be some constant value, say "changed".

Currently looking into [sample(X)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html), but not quite sure how then get those indices of the returned sample to map back to the original dataframe to change that rows' columns. Any extra suggestions or advice on how to get done what ultimately trying to do here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `shuffle` after query group2. assuming you want to random sample n

```
n=10      
x=df[df['col3'] == 'group2'].index.values    
numpy.random.shuffle(x)    
df.loc[x[:n],'tochange']='something'
```